# Manipulation of $\limsup$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability

Suppose

$$\limsup_n X_n \leq X$$

and $$Z_n - X_n \to 0$$ hold in probability if $n \to \infty$. I supposedly can add the two sides to obtain the following:

$$\limsup_n X_n +Z_n - X_n \leq X$$
holds in probability as $n \to \infty$. Hence, somehow (but I don't have rigorous justifications) to obtain that
$$Z_n \leq X$$
holds in probability as $n\to\infty$, i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}Pr(Z_n \leq X)=1.$$

Are the derivations flawed? What is a rigorous proof or counter example?

Comment: If you have a counter example, certainly I will appreciate it.

Comment: Since $Z_n \to 0$, thus $Z_n \leq X$ holds as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Ignoring the "in probability" part, $$\limsup_n (X_n + Z_n - X_n) = \limsup_n X_n + \limsup_n(Z_n - X_n) \le X + 0 = X$$ The only things it depends on is that $\limsup a_n + b_n = \limsup a_n + \limsup b_n$ and that $\lim_n b_n = 0$ implies $\limsup b_n = 0$. "With probability" introduces some complications, but the overall calculation is the same.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}Pr(Z_n \leq X)=1$ does not necessarily hold.

If $Z_n = 1/n$, and $X_n = X= 0$. Then $\limsup_n X_n \leq X$ and $Z_n - X_n \to 0$ in probability. However for every $n$, $Pr(Z_n \leq X) = 0$.

If you weaken the statement to: For every $\varepsilon>0$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}Pr(Z_n \leq X+\varepsilon)=1,$$

then it is true.

To see this firstly pick any $\delta>0$ and then pick a $N$ such that for $n\ge N$ the following are true:
$$Pr\left( X_{n}>\limsup X_n + \frac 12   \varepsilon\right) < \frac 12 \delta$$
$$Pr\left(|X_{n} - Z_{n}|\ge\frac 12 \varepsilon\right) < \frac 12 \delta$$

Then $$Pr(Z_n > X + \varepsilon) =Pr\left (\left(Z_n > X + \varepsilon \right)\land \left(X_{n}>\limsup X_n + \frac 12   \varepsilon\right) \right )+ Pr\left (\left(Z_n > X + \varepsilon \right)\land \left(X_{n}\le\limsup X_n + \frac 12   \varepsilon\right)\land\left(|(X_{n} - Z_{n}|<\frac 12 \varepsilon \right) \right )+ Pr\left (\left(Z_n > X + \varepsilon \right)\land \left(X_{n}\le\limsup X_n + \frac 12   \varepsilon\right)\land\left(|(X_{n} - Z_{n}|\ge\frac 12 \varepsilon \right) \right )$$
Exploiting the previous inequalities then yields $$Pr(Z_n > X + \varepsilon) \le \frac12 \delta +0+ \frac 12 \delta =\delta. $$

From here the desired result is clear.

Comment: Thanks for a well thoughtful answer. It looks like the conclusion in the OP can be modified. The inequality holds in probability $$\limsup_n Z_n \leq X.$$